# C++ FindWindow doesn't work

Tags: c++, findwindow

I have Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;




int main()

{

HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0,(LPCTSTR)"Skype");
if (hWnd == 0)

{

    cerr << "Cannot find window" << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

The window is called "Skype" TLoginForm in Spy++ so I use the correct name but I get the error message.(Cannot find window) I know there are lot of similar questions but i didn't get answer.

Comment: What about `hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Skype");`?

Comment: A cast means "I know what I am doing, now shut up". However, if you _do_ know what you're doing, you often don't need that cast in the first place. Irony.

Comment: A bit off-topic: Are you developing a kind of "plugin" for skype? if so, remember there's a skype API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745878 (I haven't used with C++ but C#.NET but I think C#'s one are nothing but wrappers to the C++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue may be that you're just casting a C-string to a T-string, which is probably a wide character string, so it's not going to work. Try this:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0,_T("Skype"));
```

This ensures the string constant is declared with the appropriate default character width that Windows API functions expect.

Comment: Actually, `_T` doesn't convert anything. Conversions are what happens when you cast something. This is just a macro to stick an `L` prefix on a string.

Comment: You're right, I had a brain fart and used the wrong wording. I fixed it.

Comment: @MSalters: Why use it then? I mean, Isn't easy to rather just use `L` prefix on a string than this macro?

Comment: @Jack  what the macro does depends on the compiler settings for the application. If the compiler settings specify a Unicode character set, then it will prepend the L. If the settings specify MBCS, then it does not prepend the L. Using _T guarantees that it will be correct in either case.

Comment: it does L conditionally. if UNICODE is defined. This is the standard calling style of the windows API

Comment: Along the same vein, most Windows API function calls are actually macros as well. There are 2 versions of `FindWindow`; `FindWindowA` and `FindWindowW`. `FindWindow` is a macro that resolves to `FIndWindowA` or `FindWindowW` depending on the character set configuration. Unless you are calling the A or W versions directly, you should always use `_T` to wrap your string constants.